# How to change background colour behind search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I trying to customize my `UISearchBar` in iOS7/8 and I've met next problem:
the background behind my `searchDisplayController` is always light grey. This is how it looks like:

[image]

And this is my code of some search bar customization:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x171717);
self.searchDisplayController.searchContentsController.view.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x171717);
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Is there any way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `self.view.backgroundColor` or `self.searchDisplayController.view.backgroundColor` ?

Comment: `self.view.backgroundColor` didn't help, and `searchDisplayController` didn't have property `view`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out this gray/white background is part of `refreshControl`. So all what you have to do is init it and set the needed background color:

```
self.refreshControl                 = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x232323);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it programmatically using this:

```
[searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Or try from Storyboard by changing Bar Tint:

[image]

Comment: It changes bar tint. He need change space under searchbar when you drag it down.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing the tint color of the searchable in xib 
or in code as `[self.searchDisplayController setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];searchDisplayController`